# perror: ": Connection refused" | Socket programming in C

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, ipv6

I have to do an assignment for my one lecture where i have to create a connection between a client and a server program in C. The server program and the client program have to run on different PC's. After starting the server.c with:

1. gcc server.c -o server
2. ./server   // number is part of the packet.h
   The server stops at "Listening..." which is correct.

After that i started the client.c with:

1. gcc client.c -o client
2. ./client   
   The program trows a perror ": Connection refused" after checking the connect()-function. There has to be the problem but I can't fix it.

I tried to figure out the exact problem. Here are a few things i already tried:

1. The server is 100% in my local internet. I tried with "netcat  " to search for the server and the server is there.
2. I always used a port bigger than 5000 in my home network and in my uni network 50000 (the only one that can be used, my professor told me that).
3. I was working on ubuntu and i always wrote "%eth0" behind the ipv6.
4. I checked out a bunch of other codes and mine looked nearly the same.
5. I tried to debug the "client.c" file and the connect()-function always gave back -1. I think there has to be the problem but I could not fix that.

Here is my code:
**Server.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <string.h>
// #include <libc.h>

#include "packet.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc != 4){  // Test ob 4 Programmargumente mitgegeben wurden
        fprintf(stderr, "- Error: %s <IPv6 address> <port> <sNummer>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    struct packet received_packet, send_packet;
    const char *ip = argv[1];

    char* endptr;

    long port_long = strtol(argv[2], &endptr, 10);
    if(*endptr != '\0' || port_long < 0 || port_long > UINT16_MAX){
        fprintf(stderr, "- invalid port number: %s\n", argv[2]);
        exit(1);
    }
    uint16_t port =(uint16_t)port_long;

    long sNummer_long = strtol(argv[3], &endptr, 10);
    if(*endptr != '\0' || sNummer_long < 0 || sNummer_long > UINT32_MAX){
        fprintf(stderr, "- invalid sNummer: %s\n", argv[3]);
        exit(1);
    }
    send_packet.sNummer = (uint32_t)sNummer_long; 

    int csocket;                
    struct sockaddr_in6 addr;   
    socklen_t addrsize;          
    char test[1024];            

    csocket = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    
    if(csocket < 0 ){ // Test ob TCP-Socket erstellt wurde
        perror("- socket error\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("+  TCP server socket created\n");

    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr)); 
    addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;      
    addr.sin6_port = htons(port);            
    inet_pton(AF_INET6, ip, &addr.sin6_addr); 

    if( connect(csocket, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0 ){
        perror("- could not connect to server\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("+ Connected to server %s on port %d\n",ip, port);

    printf("\n ----- message -----\n");
    printf("text: ");
    scanf("%s",send_packet.text);

    printf("s%d > %s\n",send_packet.sNummer, send_packet.text);
    send(csocket, &send_packet, sizeof(send_packet), 0); 

    ssize_t bytesRead = recv(csocket, &received_packet, sizeof(received_packet), 0); 
    if( bytesRead <= 0 ){
        perror("- error receiving data from server\n");
    }
    test[bytesRead] = '\0';
    printf("\n ----- Server -----\n");
    printf("s%d > %s\n",received_packet.sNummer,received_packet.text);

    close(csocket);
    printf("\n+ disconnected from server\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**Client.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <string.h>
// #include <libc.h>

#include "packet.h"

#define BACKLOG     5

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc != 3){  // Test ob auch 3 Programmargumente mitgegeben wurden
        fprintf(stderr, "- Error: %s <port> <sNummer>\n",argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    struct packet received_packet, response_packet;
    char* endptr;

    long port_long = strtol(argv[1], &endptr, 10);
    if(*endptr != '\0' || port_long < 0 || port_long > UINT16_MAX){
        fprintf(stderr, "- invalid port number: %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }
    uint16_t port =(uint16_t)port_long;

    long sNummer_long = strtol(argv[2], &endptr, 10);
    if(*endptr != '\0' || sNummer_long < 0 || sNummer_long > UINT32_MAX){
        fprintf(stderr, "- invalid sNummer: %s\n", argv[2]);
        exit(1);
    }
    response_packet.sNummer = (uint32_t)sNummer_long;

    int server_socket, client_socket;   
    struct sockaddr_in6 s_addr, c_addr; 
    socklen_t c_addrsize;               
    char test[1024];                    

    server_socket = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
    
    if(server_socket < 0 ){ 
        perror("- socket error\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("+  TCP server socket created\n");

    memset(&s_addr, 0, sizeof(s_addr)); 
    s_addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;      
    s_addr.sin6_port = htons(port);    
    s_addr.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;     

    if(bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &s_addr, sizeof(s_addr)) < 0){ 
        perror("- bind error\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("+ bind to port number: %d\n", port);

    if(listen(server_socket, BACKLOG) < 0){ 
        perror("- listening error, can't hear something\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Listening...\n");

    while(1){
        c_addrsize = sizeof(c_addr);
        client_socket = accept(server_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&c_addr, &c_addrsize);
        
        if(client_socket > 0){
            printf("+ Client connected\n");
        }else {
            printf("- No Client connected\n");
            sleep(1);
            continue;
        }

        ssize_t bytesRead = recv(client_socket, &received_packet, sizeof(received_packet), 0);
        if( bytesRead <= 0 ){
            perror("- error receiving data from client\n");
            continue;
        }
        test[bytesRead] = '\0';
        printf("\n ----- Client -----\n");
        printf("s%d > %s\n",received_packet.sNummer, received_packet.text);

        printf("\n ----- response -----\n");
        printf("text: ");
        scanf("%s",response_packet.text);

        send(client_socket, &response_packet, sizeof(response_packet), 0);

        close(client_socket);
        printf("\n+ Client disconnected\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and finally the **packet.h**. This packet is part of my assignment. It hast to be send from the client to the server and back.

```
#ifndef PACKET_H
#define PACKET_H

#include <stdint.h>

struct packet {
    char text[1024];
    uint32_t sNummer;
};

#endif
```

Comment: You seem to have mislabeled your code. The code you say is the server is the client.

Comment: Also note that `sizeof(received_packet) > sizeof(test)`. So `test[bytesRead] = '\0'` will write out of bounds, and lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Also please copy-paste the full and complete outputs (as text) of both the server and the client, including the actual command you use to run the programs with all their arguments.

Comment: Oh, and TCP is just a stream of bytes. There's no boundaries between messages. That means a single `recv` call could receive a *partial* message. You always need a loop to make sure you get the full message.

Comment: Please reproduce invocations (as well as errors, code, etc) completely and exactly.  `gcc server.c -o server` can't be complete as the server requires command line arguments.

Comment: I ran `./server localhost 50000 123` and `./client 50000 123` and they seem to run and connect okay for me (under Mac 14.1.2, FWIW).  That suggests to me that the problem is most likely with the IP address you are supplying for an argument, rather than with the code itself.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be nothing wrong with the code. Just make sure you are using the right ipv6 address.

On the server, run `ip address` or `ifconfig`; for `ip address`, the output will be like this:

```
1: lo:
    ...
2: eth0:
    link/ether ...
    inet <IPv4> brd ... scope ...
      ...
    inet6 <IPv6> scope ...
      ...
```

Use ipv4 or ipv6 (both work with your code). E.g.: my ipv4: `192.168.0.105/24` (you Will need `/24` part for ipv6); yours will probably be similar.

Make sure both machines are connected to same network and firewall is not causing any issues. Try disabling the firewall with `sudo ufw disable` .

And no: You don't need to write "%eth0" after the IP address.